# Constructor e Super para utilizar state ReactJs

Tags: javascript, react

Olá. Estou iniciando meus estudos de JavaScript com ReactJs e umas da minhas dúvidas seria no uso do state, não entendi muito bem pq é necessário chamar um “construtor” e um “super” passando props como parâmetro. Alguém poderia me ajudar sobre essa questão? Desde já agradeço

Comment: Leitura recomendada: [Por Que Nós Escrevemos `super(props)`?](https://overreacted.io/pt-br/why-do-we-write-super-props/).

Comment: Depende ... tem o código do exemplo minimo?

Comment: Era isso q eu precisava, mt obrigado!!!